# Cannot center Text widget inside a Column

Tags: dart, flutter

In my `MaterialApp` I have a `Column` inside a horizontal `ListView`.

**Inside** that `Column` is a `Text` widget.

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Column(
      children: [
        Text('this is the text widget'),
        // here I have another widget placed, just imagine a rectangle
      ],
  ],)
```

`textAlign: TextAlign.center,` nor surrounding it with a `Center` will change the position of the `Text`. The `Text` will always stay in the top left corner.

Also, I saw a lot about axis alignments in answers regarding similar problems, but I tried every axis settings I saw without success.

[image: illustration]

As you can see the text in the upper image is not centered.

Comment: can you post the full code . in general this can be solved using CrossAxisAlignment.center i think the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @RaoufRahiche The `ListView` is in a `Container` is in a `Column` is in a `Material`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flex/crossAxisAlignment.html)

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text('this is the text widget'),
        // here I have another widget placed, just imagine a rectangle
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

**EDIT:**

**Since, you are unsatisfied with above answer. I re-did what you exactly want**. Please refer below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'MediaQuery Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget widgetToRepeat() {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text('Hello'),
        new Container(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 150.0,
          color: Colors.green,
          margin: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            child: new ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                widgetToRepeat(),
                widgetToRepeat(),
                widgetToRepeat(),
                widgetToRepeat(),
                widgetToRepeat(),
              ],
            ),
            height: 150.0 + 16.0 + 20.0 + 16.0,
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps. I am able to achieve text at horizontally center.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer that this does not work for me.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I've edited the answer. Please check.

Comment: I am not using a `Scaffold` and I am also using `ListView.builder`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    return new ListView(children: [
  new Center(
          child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('this is the text widget'),
        // here I have another widget placed, just imagine a rectangle
      ],
    ),
  )
]);
```

warp with new Center Widget